# Issue with boolean

Tags: java, thread-safety, boolean

Hi I am still new to Java and I have a question
In the code below when is the code in "if part" of the run statement executed.
It appears the Boolean field is assigned false but if I call setRun() run is then equal to true but the statement if (run) is confusing is it executed when run is true or when its false.
Its seem simple but I cant get my head around it

```
class Sorter implements Runnable {
    /**
     * Constructs a Sorter.
     * 
     * @param values
     *            the array to be sorted
     * @param comp
     *            the component on which to display the sorting progress
     */
    private Double[] values;
    private ArrayComponent component;// This class draws and array and marks two values in the array
    private Semaphore gate;
    private static final int DELAY = 100;
    private volatile boolean run;
    private static final int VALUES_LENGTH = 30;

    public Sorter(ArrayComponent comp) {
        values = new Double[VALUES_LENGTH];
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
            values[i] = new Double(Math.random());
        this.component = comp;
        this.gate = new Semaphore(1);
        this.run = false;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the sorter to "run" mode. Called on the event dispatch thread.
     */
    public void setRun() {
        run = true;
        gate.release();
    }

    /**
     * Sets the sorter to "step" mode. Called on the event dispatch thread.
     */
    public void setStep() {
        run = false;
        gate.release();
    }

    public void run() {
        Comparator<Double> comp = new Comparator<Double>() {
            public int compare(Double i1, Double i2) {
                component.setValues(values, i1, i2);
                try {
                    if (run) Thread.sleep(DELAY);
                    else gate.acquire();
                } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
                return i1.compareTo(i2);
            }
        };
        Arrays.sort(values, comp);
        component.setValues(values, null, null);
    }

}
```

Comment: @rgettman the problem is not about understanding functionality of `if-else` statement but about how this works in a multi threaded environment, which seems to be the main problem, note that `boolean run` is `volatile` and there are methods to update it externally.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two separate threads executing.  There is the "main" thread, which is the one that is executing the main method, and a second one executing the `run()` method of your `Sorter` class.  These two execute in parallel.  On a single-core system the JVM will switch back and forth between them but on a multi-core system they will probably each be executing on their own core.

When you call `Arrays.sort()` the library routine will perform the sort and call your `compare` method every time it needs to decide which of two `Double` values comes first in the output.  The value of the `run` member is used to pause and resume the sorting process when its value is changed by the main (in this case the event-dispatch) thread, so a UI of some sort can monitor the progress of the sorting.

So, in summary:

- Main thread is updating a UI of some kind and is running *independently* of the sort thread.  It changes the value of `run` in order to control the behavior of the sort thread.
- Sort thread looks at the value of `run`. If it's `true` it waits 100ms and then proceeds with the comparison. This is probably to slow down the sort's progress so it can be visualized.  If it's false it waits to acquire some form of interlock with the UI, so the UI can display where the sort is.

The looping for the sort is outside your method in the library's `sort` method.  In your `run` method you created an instance of `Comparator<Double>` and then called `Arrays.sort()` on the `Runnable`'s thread.  `Arrays.sort()` calls your comparator's `compare()` method for each comparison (still on the runnable's thread).

On each comparison, if `run` is true, your code delays for 100ms and then returns the result of the comparison.  Otherwise it calls `gate.acquire()`, and when that returns, it proceeds to return the result of the comparison. In both cases it returns the comparison result, the only difference being in synchronization with the other thread (whatever `gate.acquire()` does).

Comment: Ok I have a further question how does the sorting actually work when run is set to true all the setRun() does is change the value of the Boolean and calls gate.realease(); .In other words where is the looping mechanism for the sorting to continue ? Is this possibly the volatile keyword which forces java to check the Boolean state or am I confused completely ?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(run)
```

will execute when run is true.

A simple way to test that for yourself is to output the value of run using this inside the If statement:

```
System.out.println("If statement ran because run is: "+run);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Java primitive boolean is automatically set to false when it is created. Your code never calls the method setRun(), so throughout the life of your code, the variable "run" is false. Because of this, your if statement

```
if(run)
```

will always evaluate to not true, and will always skip down to the else. If you would like "run" to be true, either set it initially to true where you declare it with

```
private volatile boolean run = true;
```

or call setRun() at some point.

Comment: I did not put the whole implementation there are some JButtons associated with the program so I do call it at some stage, useful explanation though :)

Answer (score -1):

`if`, `else if`, and `else` statements always check for truth. So `if(run)` is the same thing as `if(run==true)` or "if run is true then..."